# Can an annotation type without a @Target be used anywhere?

Tags: java, annotations

The Java Tutorials says what follows:

> If an @Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type T , then an annotation of type T may be written as a modifier for any declaration except a type parameter declaration.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html

Other manuals says that if @Target is not present an annotation can be used in any place except TYPE_USE or TYPE_PARAMETER scenarios.

I'm not really sure about what "parameter declaration" means in that case. This class compiles, and the annotation "@EveryWhere" is present really everywhere, without any @Target annotation. Including cast operations, lambda parameters and generics declarations.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
@interface EveryWhere{}
public @EveryWhere class  AnnotedEveryWhere<@EveryWhere T> extends @EveryWhere Object{
    @EveryWhere int i = 0;
    @EveryWhere <@EveryWhere T> String method(@EveryWhere ArrayList<@EveryWhere String> array) {
        @EveryWhere Predicate<@EveryWhere ArrayList<@EveryWhere String>> pred = 
                (@EveryWhere ArrayList<@EveryWhere String> lambdaParameter)->{
                    @EveryWhere ArrayList<@EveryWhere String> insideLambda = new @EveryWhere ArrayList<@EveryWhere String>(); 
                    return (@EveryWhere boolean) true;};
        return (@EveryWhere String) "String";
    }

}
```

Comment: "*This class compiles*" - [Cannot confirm](https://ideone.com/sj3lkG).

Comment: I think you may need to add the compiler and versions you are using. I can reproduce this in eclipse, but that may be a compiler bug. Running this in `jshell` from jdk 11 fails with lots of *annotation @EveryWhere not applicable in this type context*

Comment: Thanks a lot Ernest, I think you got the point! I was compiling it on Eclipse with different projects, with different JRE version environments (9, 11, 17). Unlike many other cases, the Eclipse compiler doesn't go "back in version" for annotations. Can we consider it a compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on Java version. Java SE 18 says

> If an @Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation
> interface T, then an annotation of type T may be written as a modifier
> for any declaration.

Unfortunately https://javaalmanac.io does not do diffs at the level of detail necessary to find out in which version it changed.

Comment: Interestingly, the JLS version 13 is the last one to mention "except a type parameter declaration", but the javadoc for `@Target` changed to match only much later in Java 17. In `javac` version 19, as of this writing, it would appear that you still cannot apply an `@Target`-less annotation to a type parameter declaration, despite the relaxation of the specification text.